# How to construct a class with a constant reference cycle?

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, c++17, move

I am writing a toy program and I accidentally created a class that I don't know how to construct.

```
struct Parent;

struct Data {
  const Parent &parent;
  // ...
  Data(const Parent &parent) : parent(parent) {}
};

struct Parent {
  const std::vector<Data> datas;
  // ...
  Parent(std::vector<Data> &&data) : datas(std::move(data)) {}
};
```

Parent has a const list of Data. Each Data has a const reference to parent. One cannot exist without the other.

I can't use this constructor

```
Parent(std::vector<Data> &&data)
```

Because I can't construct `Data` without a reference to the already existing parent. But I cannot construct `Parent` without a vector of `Data` to initialize `datas`....

How can Parent be constructed so that each `Data` object contains a const reference back to the owning `Parent` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that C++ allows self-referential declarations to create both the `Parent` and `Data` instances in the same statement:

```
Parent parent(std::vector{Data{parent}, Data{parent}});
```

I'm not sure how this design would be useful in practice, but as you said, this is just a toy program.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66095389/9614249), I was able to use a builder function that takes a `const Parent &` and builds an arbitrary vector of `Data`.

Then builder can be called from `Parent`'s member initialization list with `this`.

```
struct Parent;
struct Data {
  const Parent &parent;
  // ...
  Data(const Parent &p) : parent(p) {}
};

std::vector<Data> builder(const Parent &p) {
    std::vector<Data> datas;
    datas.emplace_back(p);
    return datas;
}

struct Parent {


  const std::vector<Data> datas;

  Parent() : datas(builder(*this)) {}
};
```

See it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/48ETrv).